# sql select statement to check for previous records for same id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I'm trying to build a query which would be checking records added for the current date. I would like to take the unique company_id for each record and check against each of these company_id's history if a records exists with almost the same document_date (previous year: f.eg.: doc date is 2014/12/31 and the previous record would have 2013/21/31).

So far I got to the point that I'm able to pull out each company_id from currently added records and show what is the latest document date available for a specific document type

In pseudo-code:

```
select company_id, MAX(document_date), document_type
from submissions
where company_id in
(
select distinct company_id
from submissions
where filing_date = current date
)
and document_type = 'annual'
group by company_id, document_type
```

I would like to be able to take the document_type value from the currently added record and check for a previous record with that same value but as mentioned where the document_date is for the previous year. Do I need to build a procedure for that or is it possible to do it in a select statement?

Comment: where company_id EXISTS

Comment: @mohan111 that's a typo there, in my statement I'm using 
"where company_id IN "

Comment: Are there two distinct date fields 'filing_date' and 'document_date'?

Comment: @JC. yes, there are, each record has a filing date and a document date as the document date refers to an end period to which the document pertains, while the filing date is when the record was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s1.company_id, s1.document_date, s2.document_date
  from submissions s1 
  join submissions s2
    on s2.company_id = s1.company_id 
   and s2.document_date = dateadd(yy, -1, s1.document_date) 
   and s2.document_type = 'annual'
   and s1.document_type = 'annual'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
; WITH cte AS (
  SELECT company_id
       , document_date
       , document_type
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY document_date DESC) As sequence
  FROM   submissions
  WHERE  document_type = 'Annual'
)
SELECT current_record.company_id
     , current_record.document_date
     , current_record.document_type
     , next_record.document_date As next_record_document_date
     , next_record.document_type As next_record_document_type
FROM   cte As current_record
 LEFT    /* outer join as we might not always have a "next" result */
  JOIN cte As next_record
    ON next_record.company_id = current_record.company_id
   AND next_record.sequence   = current_record.sequence + 1
WHERE  current_record.sequence = 1 /* Limit to the "first" record */
AND    current_record.filing_date = Current_Timestamp
;
```

This uses the windowed function `Row_Number()` to assign a... row number... to each record. The `PARTITION BY` clause resets this row number for each `company_id`. The order of the row number is determined by the `ORDER BY` part of this function (i.e. by `document_date DESC`).

Once we have this information we can then perform a self-join to get join the "current" and "next" records together.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to SELECT the documents from submissions table for the current date, and CROSS (or OUTER) APPLY it to the submissions table on the same company_id and document_type where filing_date is year from the current date:

```
select s.*, x.*
from submissions s
cross apply (
  select top (1) *
  from submissions s2
  where s.company_id = s2.company_id
  and s.document_type = s2.document_type
  and s.filing_date = dateadd(year, 1, s2.filing_date)
) x
where filing_date = @current_date
```

Pls replace the '*' with the column names needed.

`TOP (1)` is here to just pull a single row from the subquery.

Comment: Whenever you see `TOP` you should also find an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @gvee No, actually you don't have to, and you shouldn't, if you don't really care which row.

Comment: "if you don't care which row" - fair point, the OP doesn't specify which one. However I would still argue that it would be best practice to *always* include an `ORDER BY` clause so that the resultset is *more* deterministic (can only be truly deterministic if the sort condition is unique).

Comment: @gvee And I would agree with this _almost_ always. But in this particular case I don't see a point in possibly introducing an unnecessary physical sort operator.

Comment: Good point again, sir! I think this section of comments is an important consideration for the answer. I hope you don't think I was lambasting you or your contribution, I just wanted to ensure that future readers understood the implications (and IMO I would rather see newbies implement sorting every time, due to the misconceptions that catch them out when they inevitably get changed results).